# can wpf window visibility be bound with a static resource converter 'introduced' later?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have:

```
<Window x:Class="mynamespace.Menu.FloatingToolbarWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:xpui="clr-namespace:mynamespace.UI"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         Visibility="{Binding GuiItemsInstance.FloatingToolbarsView, Converter={StaticResource itemcounttovisibility}}"
         SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ToolbarContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Move to top" Click="MoveToTopClick" />
        <MenuItem Header="Move to left" Click="MoveToLeftClick"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    <xpui:MenuItemToToolbarConverter x:Key="menutotoolbarconverter" />
    <xpui:IEnumerableHasItemsToVisibilityConverter x:Key="itemcounttovisibility" />
</Window.Resources>


namespace mynamespace.UI
{
    public class IEnumerableHasItemsToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
   {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (((IEnumerable)value).GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
               return Visibility.Visible;

            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }


        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

}

And I get:

myexe.exe Error: 0 : [mynamespace.MyApp] Unhandled exception in published view 'App.FloatingToolbarWindow'. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '8' and line position '14'. ---> System.Exception: Cannot find resource named 'itemcounttovisibility'. Resource names are case sensitive.

This worked without problem before adding window visibility binding so the other converter was found and the window's content is bound to the same GuiItemsInstance.FloatingToolbarsView without any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by setting the property below resource declaration:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ToolbarContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Move to top" Click="MoveToTopClick" />
            <MenuItem Header="Move to left" Click="MoveToLeftClick"/>
        </ContextMenu>
        <xpui:MenuItemToToolbarConverter x:Key="menutotoolbarconverter" />
        <xpui:IEnumerableHasItemsToVisibilityConverter x:Key="itemcounttovisibility" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Visibility>
        <Binding Mode="TwoWay" Path="GuiItemsInstance.FloatingToolbarsView" Converter="{StaticResource itemcounttovisibility}"/>
    </Window.Visibility>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks! Guess this was answer to my question, because no more excpetion. However the converter's Convert is never called...

Comment: Are you sure it's never called? I checked on my side and it was called. Is your DataContext set to the right object?

Comment: Absolutely sure. Not initially nor when FloatingToolbarsView CollectionView changes.

Comment: Check the output window of visual studio (if you're programming with VS) for binding error. If WPF can't find the path GuiItemsInstance.FloatingToolbarsView then the converter won't be called

Comment: And DataContext is right because the other binding to the same  FloatingToolbarsView CollectionView works perfect.

Comment: thanks for your help, but output has nothing on this and as I said the window has 2 bindings to same CollectionView and the other works.

Comment: We'll need the full (relevant) XAML to check what could have gone wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99132/discussion-between-matti-and-nkoniishvt).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the answer by nkoniishvt above:
The binding has to be set on Mode="TwoWay" for the converter to be called.

```
        <Binding Mode="TwoWay" Path="GuiItemsInstance.FloatingToolbarsView" Converter="{StaticResource itemcounttovisibility}"/>
```